# Ionic2: handle a provider

Tags: typescript, ionic2

While developing a ionic2 project, I created a new provider but I have some difficulties in setting variables in MyClass.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyClass {
    token_acces: any;
    token_room: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.token_acces = null;
        this.token_room = null;
    }

    login(id,pwd){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.http.post('/localhost/',
                        JSON.stringify({
                            username: id ,
                            password: pwd
                        }), {headers : headers})
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(data=>{
                        this.token_acces = data;
                    });
    }

    getToken(){
        return this.token_acces;
    }

}
```

The main issue is that the `login()` doesn't set the `token_access` which is `null` when I call the `getToken()`.

Moreover I have a doubt, this provider is used by all the pages in my app. 
For example the homepage contains:

```
...
export class HomePage {
    id: any;
    pwd: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myClassService: MyClass) { }

    login(): void{
        this.myClassService.login(this.id, this.pwd);
        this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage, { token : this.myClassService.getToken()});
    }
}
```

If I do the same with another page, for example:

```
export class SearchPage {
    token: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myClassService: MyClass) { }
...
```

Am I using the same instance or it is a different istance of MyClass and so I can't get the values set in the previous page?

Comment: You will have the same instance if the provider is declared in `ngModule`. As for not receiving token, the http call is asynchronous and it may not have set the value yet.

Comment: At button pressing I do the http.post with the provider, after the new page is load and it is getting the value from the provider but it is still not set. How can I wait until the http.post finishes his processing?

Comment: Create an Observable on the http post in provider. Return that Observable to calling class/method. Subscribe to this Observable in calling class. Now, in calling class, do whatever you need to do in `subscribe()` of that. Look at the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160061/ionic-2-login-component-and-auth-service

Comment: Added an answer for you. Let me know if it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MyClass of your code:

```
login(id,pwd){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.http.post('/localhost/', JSON.stringify({
                        username: id ,
                        password: pwd
                    }), {headers : headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.token_acces = data;
            observer.next(data);
        },(err) => {
            console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
            observer.error(err);
        });
    });
}
```

In HomePage class or any other calling class/method of code:

```
login(): void{
    this.myClassService.login(this.id, this.pwd).subscribe((data) => {
        this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage, { token : this.myClassService.getToken()});
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log("Error occurred : ", err);
    });
}
```

You do not even need to use `getToken()`. You can just use `data` in `subscribe()` which will give you necessary data about token.

Comment: Thank you so much, it does working. Is it possibile to set a timeout?

Comment: Yes. In general, anywhere you can set timeout like `setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("Done after 3 secs");
        }, 3000);`. How you use it is up to you.