# Ionic 2 Login component and Auth service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing a simple login in my Ionic 2 app.

I have a login component that renders my login view and then sends email and password to the auth service which will validate, save a token and return true or false to the login component.

My login component:

```
export class LoginPage {

    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public authentifiction: Authentification) {}

    login() {
        this.authentifiction.login(this.email, this.password);
    }

    loginSuccess() {
        console.log('Success');
    }

    loginError() {
        console.log('Failed');
    }

}
```

And my auth service:

```
export class Authentification {

    public authorized: boolean;

    constructor(public http: Http, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public storage: Storage) {}

    login(email, password) {
        var params = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this.http.post('URL', params, {
            headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this.loginSuccess(data.auth_token),
                error => this.loginError()
        );
    }

    loginSuccess(auth_token) {
        this.storage.set('auth_token', auth_token);
        ???
    }

    loginError() {
        ???
    }

}
```

How can I have the auth service return true or false depending if the login was successful or not?

This entire observable thing is still a bit confusing to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not return directly a boolean, because the http request doesn't reply immediatly.
Instead, you return an observable to the caller, telling him "I do not have the answer yet but here is an observable that will notice you the answer once I have it".
Then the caller just subscribes to this observable (like a mailing list), and receives a signal (like receiving an email) with the answer.

```
login(email, password): Observable<boolean> {
...
return this.http.post('URL', params, {
  headers: headers
}).map(res => {
  this.storage.set('auth_token', res.json().auth_token);
  return true;
});
```

And from the caller:

```
login() {
 this.authentifiction.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(res => {
   console.log('success');
 }, error => {
   console.log('error');
 });
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the sort and understandable explanation of observables. I implemented your code but in my auth service I get: Cannot find 'Observable'. Do I have to import some other lib?

Comment: Yes, you can use import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: Also, I would like to add that the type of response you want, like, true or false on login, you can implement it on your server's POST service, where you are doing this HTTP POST call.