# Executing an observble only when a promise is resolved in angular2/ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an authentication service which saves the token and the result of saving the token is a promise. I would like the value to be returned to another function only after the promise is resolved.

This is my authservice which saves the token:

```
login(user: UserModel): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.postnoAuth(this.loginurl + "mobile-login", body)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;

            if (token){
                this._storage.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify({token: token}))
                .then(res=>{
                     return true; //return true after the promise is resolved
                });
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        })
    //.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then I am subscribing to the above:

```
this._authservice.login(this.user).subscribe(respose => {
    if(response){  //expecting true here
        console.log("true");
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
    }
    loader.dismiss();
        this.submitted = false;
    },
    error=> {
        this.submitted = false;
    }
);
```

Above code always logs false, even when the value of storage has been set, What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this via `flatMap` operator. The `flatMap` operator helps us to call one request after the previous one completed:

```
return this._http.get('app/test.json')
  .flatMap((response: Response) => {
    let token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;

    if (token) {
      return this._storage.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token }))
        .then(res => {
          return true;
        });
    } else {
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
  });
```

Don't foget these imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6OYAVfDuP0G95j1yGoOy?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You are returning both an Observable and a boolean value from `Login()`. Decide what you want to return.

If you want a boolean value, redefine your method like this:

```
login(user: UserModel): Boolean {
    this._http.postnoAuth(this.loginurl + "mobile-login", body)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;

            if (token){
                this._storage.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify({token: token}))
                .then(res=>{
                    return true;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Some error while setting storage :", err);
                    return false;
                });
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        })
    //.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Or return an observable. Now, I am not sure if `postnoAuth()` already returns an observable. If it does not you can create new one like I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158110/ionic2-handle-a-provider/42175470#42175470). E.g. put your code in `Observable.create(observer => {},(err)=>{});`. Then, subscribe to `login()` from your calling method and set to storage from here. So, your promise will be in calling method. Your code will become like this:

```
login(user: UserModel): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this._http.postnoAuth(this.loginurl + "mobile-login", body)
        .map((response: Response)
        .subscribe(data => {
            observer.next(data);
        },
        (err) => {
            observerer.error();
        }
    });
}
```

And subscribe from calling method :

```
this._authservice.login(this.user).subscribe(respose => {
    let token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;
    if (token){
        this._storage.set('currentUser', JSON.stringify({token: token}))
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Some error while setting storage :", err);
        });
    }
);
```

I think for what you are looking for 1st method in my answer should work. But, 2nd method is what I would suggest. The flow is much easier in 2nd. Your choice.